# Is it possible to multiply two 2-digit numbers using three 1-digit multiplication?

Tags: algorithms

e.g. we have 2 two digit integer numbers (17 and 25) to multiply. but we can only multiply 2 one digit number ($5×7$, $5×1$ etc.) and we can only multiply 3 times ($5×7,5×1,2×7$)

Comment: By the distributive property of multiplication over addition, $17 \cdot 25 = (10 + 7) \cdot (20 + 5) = 10\cdot 20 + 10\cdot 5 + 7\cdot 20 + 7\cdot 5$.  Note that $10\cdot 20$ is essentially multiplication of two 1-digit numbers.  I don't see how to reduct the number of 1-digit multiplications from four to three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [*Karatsuba algorithm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) (which is usually used for much larger numbers) almost does the trick.

Write $x = 10x_1 + x_0$ and $y = 10y_1 + y_0$ where $x_0,y_0 < 10$. Then we have
$$xy = 100(x_1y_1) + 10\left[(x_1+x_0)(y_1+y_0)-x_1y_1-x_0y_0\right]+ x_0y_0,$$

which uses only three multiplications. (The trick is that $x_0y_0$ and $x_1y_1$ need only be calculated once each and can be reused.) The middle product possibly uses two-digit numbers, however.

Here's an example that works because the digits are small enough:

> $x=16, y=35$:
>
> $\begin{align}
> xy &= 100(1\cdot3) + 10[(1+6)(3+5)-1\cdot3-6\cdot5] + 6\cdot5\\
> &=300 + 10(56-3-30) + 30\\
> &=300 + 230 + 30\\
> &=560
> \end{align}$

We can manipulate the expression to avoid having to multiply two-digit numbers in the middle product; this effectively yields the answer given by @Michael.

Answer (score 4):

$\overline{ab}\times\overline{cd} = 100(ac)+ 10(ad+bc) + (bd)$
so the trick is to find $(ad+bc)$ in one multiply:
 $ad+bc = (a-b)(d-c)+ac+bd$

$\overline{54}\times\overline{73}=100(5*7)+10*(5*3+4*7)+(4*3)\\
5*3+4*7=(5-4)*(3-7)+5*7+3*4\\43=-1*4+5*7+3*4$

Answer (score 0):

Not every single multiplication pair can be written as that. There are two counterexamples:

1. Multiply two 2-digit prime numbers, like $19\times 37$. You can't represent them using only three 1-digit numbers and multiplication, because you can't factor them using smaller, 1-digit factors.
2. Take larger powers of smaller 1-digit numbers, like $64\times 81$. You can decompose it only as a product of four 1-digit numbers: $8\times8\times9\times9$

Comment: Why is it obvious?

Comment: How do you decompose prime numbers as product of smaller factors? Anyway, edited for clarity.

Comment: Michael's answer shows that it is in fact possible (but not obvious) to do such a thing. You don't need to decompose the numbers into their prime factors.

Comment: The way I interpreted the question, we could only multiply numbers, not add them. So my answer will be out of context.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Karatsuba algorithm, which was discovered in 1960.

Wikipedia has a nice discussion:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm